# How do I serialize a class inherited from List<T> with custom parameter to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have a class that is inherited from List

```
[Serializable]
public class ListWithVersion<T> : List<T>
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "version")]
    public int version;

    public ListWithVersion(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    {
    }

    public ListWithVersion() : base()
    {

    }
}
```

And I serialize it to XML like this

```
ListWithVersion<Chapter> lwv = new ListWithVersion<Chapter>();
        Chapter chapter = new Chapter();
        chapter.dialogs = new List<Dialog>();
        lwv.version = 1;
        lwv.Add(chapter);

        Serialize("lwv.xml", typeof(ListWithVersion<Chapter>), extraTypes, lwv);

    private void Serialize(string name, Type type, Type[] extraTypes, object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type, extraTypes);
            using (var fs = new FileStream(GetPathSave() + name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(fs, obj);
            }
        }
        catch (XmlException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("serialization exception, " + name + " Message: " + e.Message);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("exc while ser file '" + name + "': " + ex.Message);
            System.Exception exc = ex.InnerException;
            int i = 0;
            while (exc != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("inner " + i + ": " + exc.Message);
                i++;
                exc = exc.InnerException;
            }
        }
    }
```

But the XML file does not contain the version parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<ArrayOfChapter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Chapter id="0">
    <dialogs />
  </Chapter>
</ArrayOfChapter>
```

(version="1.0" is not my parameter)

I have tried XmlAttribute instead of XmlElement and also have tried just raw

```
public int version;
```

Nothing has helped to get the version parameter in the XML.

So how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do that directly, because `XmlSerializer` has a special handling for objects that are `ICollection<T>` which (as you've noticed) pretty much ignores the class and just serializes its contents. Two options:

- Implement `IXmlSerializable` and do your own serialization.
- Modify your class to have a member of type `List<T>` instead of inheriting from it.

EDIT: I'll answer your comment here, as it's easier with formatted text. You could do that, but that would probably require a mix of both approaches.

1. Have a private `List<T>` inside your class.
2. Have your class implement `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`. Use the private list to implement all interface members, something like:

---

```
public void Add(T item) => this.list.Add(item);

public void Clear() => this.list.Clear();

[...]
```

3. Implement `IXmlSerializable` - first write your own variable, then use the private list to output everything else.

Comment: can I implement it in a way when at first I write the value of version parameter and then use default ICollection<T>'s implementation?

Comment: @user2686299 Updated my answer